# Datatables gets confused with my bootstrap class on select-filter column filtering

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, datatables

When I use Datatables column filtering with their built in select filter it gets confused with my `<span class="label label-success"> Active </span>` and returns this:

[image: This is the select fields that it makes]

I would like it to not have the " Deleted "> Deleted " etc. and just return Deleted, Active, Inactive so the filtering works properly.

My Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#questionnaireTable').DataTable( {
            select: {
                style: 'multi'
            },
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every( function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        } );

                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                       select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                     } );
                } );
             }
        } );
 } );
```

And Blade Engine (Laravel) returning the Html:

```
                 <td>
                    @if($questionnaire->deleted_at) 
                        <span class="label label-danger"> Deleted </span> 
                    @elseif($questionnaire->status == \App\Models\Questionnaire::STATUS_ACTIVE) 
                        <span class="label label-success"> Active </span> 
                    @elseif($questionnaire->status == \App\Models\Questionnaire::STATUS_INACTIVE)
                        <span class="label label-warning"> Inactive </span>
                    @else
                        <span class="label label-danger"> Invalid Status </span>
                    @endif
                </td>
```

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
   select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
} );
```

I think because in the code above, when in the loop, `d = '<span class="label label-danger"> Deleted/Active... </span>'`.

You can get only the text in the span before you make the option string by using `$(d).text()`

Comment: Thanks for the help!!